# How to make a PHP Regex Option-Group not eager?

Tags: php, regex, nlp

I have a regex that looks for a pattern ending with an option group of ngrams. Here is the regex:

```
$regex = '/.{0,150}\b(is (.{0,50}?)\b(assembler|builder|consulter|contracter|contractor|contract manufacturer|converter|designer|distributer|distributor|engineerer|fabricater|fabricator|formulater|formulator|installer|machiner|manufacturer|offerer|producer|provider|reseller|seller|supplier|wholesaler|machine shop|job shop|law firm|marketer|marketing agency))\b([^.!?<>]{0,150})\b/'
```

Here is the string I'm matching on:

```
$string = 'ABC Company Inc. is a Distributor, Fabricator, and Manufacturer of textiles. Another sentence.';
```

The goal is to extract "is a Distributor, Fabricator, and Manufacturer" with the first capturing group of the regex. The rest of the regex is just to define context, and ideally, usually ends at the end of a sentence or after a certain length.

Right now, my first capturing group is eager and is matching only "is a Distributor".  How can I make this not eager?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little shorter version without duplication (not in code-tag, because one-line isn't readable):

```
.{0,150}\b(is([^.!?<>]{0,50}(assembler|builder|consulter|contracter|contractor|contract manufacturer|converter|designer|distributer|distributor|engineerer|fabricater|fabricator|formulater|formulator|installer|machiner|manufacturer|offerer|producer|provider|reseller|seller|supplier|wholesaler|machine shop|job shop|law firm|marketer|marketing agency))+)\b([^.!?<>]{0,150}\b)
```

The idea is to allow prefixes not longer than 50 symbols (luckily, there is only one such constant, so it is easy to find it) before each keyword, no matter if it is another keyword in an enumeration. In order to catch enumeraion I added `+)` after the keywords list.

Check [here](https://regex101.com/r/fD5kV4/1).

Answer (score 1):

```
.{0,150}\b(is (.{0,50}?)\b(assembler|builder|consulter|contracter|contractor|contract manufacturer|converter|designer|distributer|distributor|engineerer|fabricater|fabricator|formulater|formulator|installer|machiner|manufacturer|offerer|producer|provider|reseller|seller|supplier|wholesaler|machine shop|job shop|law firm|marketer|marketing agency)(.*?\b(assembler|builder|consulter|contracter|contractor|contract manufacturer|converter|designer|distributer|distributor|engineerer|fabricater|fabricator|formulater|formulator|installer|machiner|manufacturer|offerer|producer|provider|reseller|seller|supplier|wholesaler|machine shop|job shop|law firm|marketer|marketing agency))*)\b([^.!?<>]{0,150})\b
```

This super long regex can do that .See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/sJ9gM7/39